# how to fix the error android.database.cursorindexoutofboundsexception?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Anyone? please help me to figure this out. I'm getting an android.database.cursorindexoutofboundsexception error and I don't why. I'm sure that I name my columns correct but still I got it. What I am trying to do is just to get the companycode of the given company name.

Here my code my DatabaseAdapter

```
public Cursor getCompanyCode(String company)
{
    Cursor c = dbSqlite.query(Constants.DATABASE_TABLE_COMPANY,
            new String[] { Constants.DATABASE_COLUMN_ID,
                            Constants.COMPANY_CODE,Constants.COMPANY_NAME},
            Constants.COMPANY_CODE+" = ?",
            new String[]{company}, null, null, null);

    if (c != null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

and here another code to get company code of the given company

```
Cursor companyCode = databaseAdapter.getCompanyCode(company);
code = companyCode.getString(companyCode.getColumnIndex(Constants.COMPANY_CODE));
```

and here is my logcat.

```
06-04 12:54:48.085: E/AndroidRuntime(27134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uni.customercare/com.uni.customercare.ViewSummaryActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Comment: Have You tried to check if cursor contains any records (e.g. retur value of  moveToFirst() or getCount())?

Comment: no. I don't know how. I tried to put it in a toast to see if there's a value but my app is crashing.

Comment: Try to call companyCode.getCount() before getString() to ensure that it contains records.

Comment: @sandrstar it returns 0 value. what should I do?

Comment: it means that the cursor is empty => query returned 0 records. Ensure that db contains the record with COMPANY_CODE==company which You're trying to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

define this method in your database helper class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Use an instance of the class to call this method.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getCompanyDetails(){

        HashMap<String,String> company= new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_COMPANY; //Change this query accordingly.

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            company.put(KEY_COMP_ID, cursor.getString(0));
            company.put(KEY_COMP_CODE, cursor.getString(1));
            company.put(KEY_COMP_NAME, cursor.getString(2));

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return company;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to work with cursor companyCode..

```
companyCode.moveToFirst();
while( !companyCode.isAfterLast() ) {
    //do something with companyCode..
    //.....
    companyCode.moveToNext();
}
companyCode.close()
```